# selecting author in table1 and count published book  in table2 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database that looks like this

members table1

```
id | memberid | name | password
-------------------------------
```

Journal table2

```
id | memberid | title | desc
-----------------------------
```

i want to select all members from table one, joining with the result journal_count of each member in table 2. Am trying to count the number of times each memberid appears in table2

Am using mysql and php, can someone help me with this query

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select m.memberid,m.name,count(j.memberid) as total
from members as m
left join journal as j
on m.memberid = j.memberid
group by m.memberid
```

P.S. If your table has a field named desc, beware that this is a reserved word and it would be better to rename it. Otherwise you'll always have to put it within backticks.

```
select m.memberid,m.name,count(j.memberid) as total
from members as m
left join journal as j
on m.memberid = j.memberid
where m.memberid = $memberid
group by m.memberid
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i also need to select all infor for one member in the members table and count all journals by this member in journal table using memberid

Comment: Add a where clause to select your desired id.

Comment: hello, when i do this `select members.*, count(journals.memberid) as jcount from members, journals where members.memberid = '$membersid' AND journals.memberid='$membersid' group by journals.memberid` i don't get any result. although there is no data in there is no entry fot the specified memeberid in the journals table, at least i should get the memebers.* information. MySql is not returning anything, and there is no error

Answer (score 2):

```
select members.name, count(journal.memberid) as journal_count from members, journal where members.memberid = journal.memberid group by journal.memberid
```

Comment: i get and error `Unknown column 'journal.memberid' in 'field list'`. lwhat could be the cause?

Comment: make sure that table name is journal and journal table has a field name memberid

Comment: hello, when i do this `select members.*, count(journals.memberid) as jcount from members, journals where members.memberid = '$membersid' AND journals.memberid='$membersid' group by journals.memberid` i don't get any result. although there is no data in there is no entry fot the specified memeberid in the journals table, at least i should get the memebers.* information. MySql is not returning anything, and there is no error

Comment: Try to make sure you are making the query right, (print it and do it using mysql console or any tool like sqlyog) try this: select members.*, count(journals.memberid) as jcount from members, journals where members.memberid = journals.memberid AND journals.memberid='$membersid' group by journals.memberid